# Shift invariance of the Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to write a brief introduction to the Lebesgue integration in $\mathbb{R}^m$ from the general viewpoint. The students do not specialize in this field. So I formulate a theorem without proof.

Theorem. In $\mathbb{R}^m$ there is a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ and a measure $\mu:\Sigma\to [0,\infty]$ such that

1. the space of continuous functions with compact support $C_0(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is dense in $L^1(\mu,\mathbb{R}^m)$;
2. the Lebesgue integral matches with the Riemann integral  on the space $C_0(\mathbb{R}^m)$;
3. if $A\subset B\in\Sigma$ and $\mu(B)=0$ then $A\in\Sigma$.

Almost all goes  nice but I can not deduce  the equality  $\mu(D)=\mu(D+h),\quad D\in\Sigma,\quad h\in\mathbb{R}^m$ from this theorem. I actually can not prove that $D+h$ is measurable whenever $D$ is measurable.

For example let $I_D\in L^1$ then we have $\psi_i\to I_D$ almost everywhere and in $L^1,\quad \psi_i\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^m)$. This implies that $\psi_i\to I_D$ pointwise in $\mathbb{R}^m\smallsetminus Q,\quad\mu(Q)=0$.   Then $\widetilde\psi_i(x)=\psi_i(x-h)\to I_{D+h}$ pointwise in $\mathbb{R}^m\smallsetminus (Q+h)$. And I am stuck since the next step requires information on whether $Q+h$ is measurable.

Comment: Notice that $\sigma$-algebra is typographically different from $\sigma-$algebra. The former uses a hyphen and the latter a minus sign. The former usage is correct and I edited accordingly. Also $A\backslash B,$ using `\backslash`, differs from $A\setminus B,$ using `\setminus`, in the that latter has the horizontal spacing proper to a binary relation symbol. That one I changed to $A\smallsetminus B.$

Comment: It seems like your axioms underspecify what the sigma algebra is. Surely you need some natural hypotheses on it (such as: contains every open set / contains every compact set / complete in some sense etc).

Comment: Abstract theory of  measure and integration is supposed to be known. That is about the Lebesgue in $\mathbb{R}^m$ only. The facts that each open or closed  set is measurable and each compact is integrable  can be deduced from 1)-3)

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to answer because you do not ask one, at least not explicitly. Do you want to know if (1)-(3) imply that $\Sigma$ is Lebesgue measurable sets?

Comment: I want to know is it possible to deduce $\mu(D+h)=\mu(D)$ from 1)-3)

Comment: One way is to prove a convenient uniqueness result, so that the equality follows because $D\mapsto \mu(D+h)$ also satisfies 1,2,3.

Comment: I think you have made matters more complicated in an attempt to simplify them. One now has to fight the ghosts of extensions of Lebesgue measure to larger $\sigma$-algebras, an issue that is completely avoided in the usual approach. Of course, the question itself is still valid and interesting, but the approach doesn't feel like a good "easy" introduction to the subject.

Comment: I also suspect this is false, though I'm admittedly anything but sure about the technical details. Basic idea: take the standard non-measurable subset $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ and extend Lebesgue measure to the larger $\sigma$-algebra obtained by including this set, with $\mu(A)=0$. I don't think this $\sigma$-algebra will be translation invariant.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need this on all of $\Sigma$, rather than just on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra or its completion?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, what you [say](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444945/shift-invariance-of-the-lebesgue-measure#comment1149078_444945) about `$\sigma-$` vs. `$\sigma$-` and `\backslash` vs. `\setminus` is of course correct—and thank you for the tidying!—but surely `\tilde` vs. `\widetilde` is a matter of taste.  Personally, I find $\tilde\psi_i$ nicer than $\widetilde\psi_i$, but, in matters like this where I think that there is no universally agreed semantically correct solution, it shouldn't really be up to you or to me, only to the post author.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I thought about that too, but the indicator of a nonmeasurable set is probably not approximable by continuous functions.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I would give the set measure zero, so the indicator function is not even a new element of $L^1$ (it is $=0$ a.e.).

Comment: @ChristianRemling Point taken.